# achartengine Bar Chart from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, achartengine

Im trying to create an achartengine bar chart from data in my sqlite database, but when I attempt to populate the dataset for the bar chart I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

TestAdapter.java

```
public Cursor getDaysGraphDataY()
{
    try
    {
        String sql ="SELECT data FROM v_data_main WHERE datatype = 'd' ORDER BY CAST(number AS INTEGER) DESC";

        Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (mCur!=null)
        {
            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
        return mCur;
    }
    catch (SQLException mSQLException)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "getDaysGraphDataY >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}

public Cursor getDaysGraphDataX()
{
    try
    {
        String sql ="SELECT number FROM v_data_main WHERE datatype = 'd' ORDER BY CAST(number AS INTEGER) DESC";

        Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (mCur!=null)
        {
            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
        return mCur;
    }
    catch (SQLException mSQLException)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "getDaysGraphDataX >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
```

BarChart.java

```
public class BarGraph{

public Intent getIntent(Context context) 
{   
    // Bar 1
    //int[] y = { 124, 135, 443, 456, 234, 123, 342, 134, 123, 643, 234, 274 };
    //context = context.getApplicationContext();
    TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(context);
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();

    Cursor getDataY = mDbHelper.getDaysGraphDataY();
    Cursor getDataX = mDbHelper.getDaysGraphDataX();

    int rowsY = getDataY.getCount();
    int rowsX = getDataX.getCount();

    getDataY.moveToFirst();
    getDataX.moveToFirst();

    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Demo Bar Graph 1");
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsY; i++) {
        series.add(getDataX.getString(i), getDataY.getInt(i));
        getDataY.moveToNext();
        getDataX.moveToNext();
    }
    mDbHelper.close();
    /*
    // Bar 2
    int[] y2 = { 224, 235, 243, 256, 234, 223, 242, 234, 223, 243, 234, 274 };
    CategorySeries series2 = new CategorySeries("Demo Bar Graph 2");
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        series2.add("Bar " + (i+1), y2[i]);
    }
    */

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
    //dataset.addSeries(series2.toXYSeries());

    // This is how the "Graph" itself will look like
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("Demo Graph Title");
    mRenderer.setXTitle("X VALUES");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Y VALUES");
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.GREEN);
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.RED);
    // Customize bar 1
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    // Customize bar 2
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataset,mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
    return intent;
}
```

}

I have tried adding an _id column as suggested in another question and also uninstalling the app and reinstalling.

Here is the full logcat:

```
    04-16 17:38:23.625 3334-3334/? E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 1, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 30 rows, 1 columns.
04-16 17:38:23.629 3334-3334/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-16 17:38:23.630 3334-3334/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.marnistek.serverstats, PID: 3334
                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
                                                     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                     at com.marnistek.serverstats.BarGraph.getIntent(BarGraph.java:36)
                                                     at com.marnistek.serverstats.GraphAChartEngineActivity.barGraphHandler(GraphAChartEngineActivity.java:27)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing my loop from:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsY; i++) {
    series.add(getDataX.getString(i), getDataY.getInt(i));
    getDataY.moveToNext();
    getDataX.moveToNext();
}
```

To:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        series.add(getData.getString(getData.getColumnIndex("number")), getData.getInt(getData.getColumnIndex("data")));
        getData.moveToPosition(i);
    }
```

I also changed it to use just one cursor to get all the columns I needed from the db, instead of having a separate cursor for each the X and the Y axes

Answer (score 1):

These exceptions occurred while trying to fetch primitive values ( int, long ) from the Cursor. Unfortunately, neither exception explained much about what the problem really was. It is also important to mention that these exceptions were not correlated to any particular Android API version, nor to a specific device manufacture.

Please follow this link for more details:
http://blog.tapreason.com/2014/03/02/how-to-resolve-java-lang-illegalstateexception-couldnt-read-row-0-col-y-from-cursorwindow-make-sure-the-cursor-is-initialized-correctly-before-accessing-data-from-it/